# KendoUI Append Pane on Splitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, splitter

I am appending a new panel on KendoUI splitter

```
var newPane = splitter.append({
  size: "100%",
  collapsible: true
});

$("#splitter").css("overflow", "auto");
$("#splitter").css("background-color", "#eee");
$("#splitter").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
```

and loading content via Ajax

```
splitter.ajaxRequest(".k-pane:last", "/incidents/ajax/show/" + data);
```

It returns a div like

```
<div role="group" class="k-pane k-scrollable" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 1248px; height: 805px; left: 8px;">
.....content....
</div>
```

How can i add `id="something"` to the new pane please?

I tried

```
$('.k-pane:last').attr("id", "something")
```

without success, any advice please?

Comment: `$('.k-pane:last div.k-pane').attr("id", "something")` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response (again),
it didn't work, it keeps it `<div role="group" class="k-pane k-scrollable" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 1265px; height: 805px; left: 8px;">` :/

Comment: Full code:
`$("#grid").on("click", ".toggleShowIncident2", function() {
var data = $(this).data('id');
var desc = $(this).data('desc');
$("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
panes: [ { collapsible: false }, { collapsible: false } ]
});
var splitter = $("#splitter").data("kendoSplitter");
var newPane = splitter.append({
size: "100%",
collapsible: true
});
  
$("#splitter").css("overflow", "auto");
....
$('.k-pane:last div.k-pane').attr("id", "newpane2");
console.log(newPane, "test");
splitter.ajaxRequest(".k-pane:last", "/incidents/ajax/show/" + data);`

Comment: [Check this](https://dojo.telerik.com/acAdesoR)

Comment: Indeed ! It works now !! Like this: `$("#splitter .k-pane:last").attr("id", "newpane2");` Thank you very very very much ! Please fill up the answer so i can vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select the whole path since the root element:

```
$("#yourelement .k-pane:last").attr("id", "something");
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/acAdesoR)